# Why do parts of my Emacs buffer turn invisible when I'm writing elisp?

Tags: debugging, visibility

When I'm writing elisp code, parts of the buffer that I press enter on turn invisible (i.e. they get the property `invisible` set to `t`). I haven't been able to reproduce this reliably, because it doesn't happen when I write nonsensical code to just produce some lines, but it happens sometimes.

Here is what I know:

- I'm using Emacs 26.1 on Mac OS
- Here is the list of active modes when I press `C-h m`: Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
  Blink-Cursor Cl-Old-Struct-Compat Diff-Auto-Refine Electric-Indent
  Erc-Autojoin Erc-Button Erc-Fill Erc-Irccontrols Erc-List Erc-Match
  Erc-Menu Erc-Move-To-Prompt Erc-Netsplit Erc-Networks Erc-Noncommands
  Erc-Pcomplete Erc-Readonly Erc-Ring Erc-Stamp Erc-Track Erc-Track
  File-Name-Shadow Flx-Ido Font-Lock Global-Font-Lock Global-Voice-Lock
  Ido-Everywhere Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Projectile Shell-Dirtrack Tooltip
  Transient-Mark Voice-Lock

How can I identify what is doing this?

Comment: Start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file). If you cannot repro the problem that way then bisect your init file to find the culprit. Do not expect to have a giant sack of stuff involved (e.g. all those modes active) and be able to debug your problem. Narrow it down. Bisecting your init file is a binary search - very quick. You can do it using command `comment-region` (with `C-u` it uncomments).

Comment: In addition to Drew's good advice, I'd be suspicious of all those ERC modes, which really aren't applicable to write Emacs Lisp code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @Drew's advice, I figured that it was because of a bubg in Emacspeak and the way it dealt with overlays, particularly the ones that `company` created. This has been fixed in the recent versions of Emacspeak.